# Sqlite Browser does not launch on Windows 7

Tags: sqlite-browser

I have downloaded the Sqlite browser from the official website.
I installed it without any error but after I installed if I try to launch the SQLite browser it shows the following error.

```
The application was unable to start correctly(0x000007b). Click ok to close the application.
```

I have tried reinstalling it but the same error occurs.
Note:I am new here so if my question was not clear please ask for the details

Answer (score 0):

I have found a fix for the above error. Using the nightly build of the DB browser which is available on their official site seems to avoid the problem.